# NoSuchMethodError после обновления

Tags: java, android, gradle, exoplayer

У меня есть submodule ExoPlayer для моего проекта. Я сделал всего одно изменение в этом модуле (оно небольшое, всего лишь добавление бесполезной переменной) и запушил его. Затем обновил ExoPlayer с версии 2.13.2 до 2.13.3 с помощью команды гита:
`git remote add origin2 https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer.git`
`git pull origin2 release-v2 --rebase`

После этого приложение при запуске видео начало выдавать следующую ошибку в Runtime:

```
Unexpected error loading stream
      java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method sharedInitializeOrWait(ZJ)V in class Lcom/google/android/exoplayer2/util/TimestampAdjuster; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.TimestampAdjuster' appears in /data/app/com.adisalagic.**==/base.apk)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaChunk.loadMedia(HlsMediaChunk.java:395)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaChunk.load(HlsMediaChunk.java:355)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:415)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
2021-04-22 17:10:15.625 27176-27312/com.adisalagic.** E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: ExoPlayer:Playback
```

При использовании библиотеки без submodule все работает как должно.

Мой Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.wormhole'

android {
    compileSdkVersion wormhole(29)
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'
    lintOptions {
        disable 'RestrictedApi'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.adisalagic.**"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.20-alpha"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}



dependencies {
   
    ...
    
    implementation project(':exoplayer-library-core')
    implementation project(':exoplayer-library-dash')
    implementation project(':exoplayer-library-ui')
    implementation project(':exoplayer-library-hls')
    implementation project(':exoplayer-library-common')

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

}
```

Для создания submodule я использовал [этот гайд](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/dev-v2/README.md#locally).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если исследовать [исходники ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer), то совершенно точно видно, что авторы как раз и правили код относящийся к классу `TimestampAdjuster`, который и вызывает у вас проблему

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Самое разумное залезть в исходники в субмодуле и откатить изменения в `loadModule()` назад.

Comment: Это действительно решило проблему, но почему такое вообще произошло?

Comment: Никто не застрахован от ошибок - не боги пишут код, а обычные кодеры, такие же как и мы с вами :) Имеет смысл выставить баг-репорт

Comment: Если скачивать как обычную библиотеку, то она работает как часы

Comment: Это всего лишь означает, что эти изменения еще не выложены на репо.